# Animate StackPanel height code-behind

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to make an expandable/collapsible `StackPanel` controlled with a `CheckBox`. First I tried to do that directly in XAML but I couldn't achieved it easy way. It's not a problem for me to have some code-behind for this task. So far I have:

```
private void activateCheck_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoubleAnimation expand = new DoubleAnimation(200, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
    expandableStack.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, expand);
}
```

But I get an AnimationException that says:

> Cannot animate the 'Height' property on a 'System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel' using a 'System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation'. For details see the inner exception.

What's wrong here?

Comment: And what says the inner exception?

Comment: "'System.Windows.Media.DoubleAnimation' cannot use default origin value of 'NaN'"

Comment: Then give `StackPanel.Height` some value so that it is not `NaN`.

Comment: Or set the animation's `From` property.

Answer (score 7):

When you do not explicitly specify a start value for the animation by setting the [`From`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.from.aspx) property, the animation starts at the current value of the property. If that is `NaN` however, the animation does not know where to start.

Hence you have two options, either you exlicitly set the StackPanel's `Height`

```
var expand = new DoubleAnimation(200, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
expandableStack.Height = 0;
expandableStack.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.HeightProperty, expand);
```

or you tell the animation where to start

```
var expand = new DoubleAnimation(0, 200, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
expandableStack.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.HeightProperty, expand);
```

In case you want to start at the current height, you may use `ActualHeight` as start value:

```
var expand = new DoubleAnimation(expandableStack.ActualHeight,
                                 200, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
expandableStack.BeginAnimation(StackPanel.HeightProperty, expand);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot animate width and height properties (or any other properties of type double) if they are by default unset (in that case their value will be NaN). So alternatively you can achieve it with ScaleTransform. Please check this blog article. Hope it helps.

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/animating-width-and-height-when-they-are-double-nan/

Comment: That's not true. You may simply set the animation's `From` property.

Comment: So isn't that mean we are setting some value to start the animation ?

Comment: Exactly. If you do not explicitly specify a start value by setting `From`, the animation starts at the current property value. However, if the current value is `NaN`, the animation doesn't know where to start and throws an exception.

Comment: So this is what i said in my answer, cannot animate Width and Height if they are by default unset(their value will be NaN). You have to have some initialization to start the animation.